# Domain Options Not Populating for Enterprise/Portal hosted feature layer when accessing in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-portal, domains

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.5. I am trying to apply an existing domain within a feature class to a new field. All of the documentation I have read on this indicates that in the Fields View for a feature layer, clicking on the Domain field should prompt a dropdown with the domain options in the layer.
[image: Fields Table]

When I open the Domains view for the feature class, there is a notification at the top that domains for the workspace are read-only. So I can imagine the read-only setting for the domains in the workspace may be creating a problem. But I'm not trying to change any domains - just trying to apply an existing domain to a new field.

[image: Domains Table]

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to assign a domain to OBJECTID field? If so, you cannot as OBJECTID is system field and it is read-only too.

On the other hand, domain field type must match with field data type, i.e. text->text, long->long.